Digital transistor check
Is there any guide to check a digital transistor?
Assuming a digital PNP transistor (e.g. KEC Semiconductor KRA106S) with R1 = 4.7 kΩ & R2 = 47 kΩ (see diagram below).
If I don't get any voltage between base and emitter (VBE) using DVM diode mode, but I get resistance in OHM mode between B&E does it means that the transistor is faulty?

Image adapted from: KEC Semiconductor KRA106S datasheet

What test current does your DVM use in diode mode?

Usual diode mode in DVM- for normal transistor I usually gets 0.5-0.7 volts  - it should work the same for digital transistor?

(If people are unfamiliar with the term "digital transistor" (aka "pre-biased transistor" or "pre-bias transistor") it was part of this Q&A: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/294315/pre-biased-bipolar-transistor-bjt-tradeoffs )

Digital transistor is https://wmsc.lcsc.com/wmsc/upload/file/pdf/v2/lcsc/1804140010_KEC-Semicon-KRA106S-RTK-P_C112789.pdf      - Just need to know if DVM mode diode can be used to confim VBE dtop volrage  - PN is KRA106S

@AmiCohen Is this a one-off test or will you be testing more than a few? What are the criteria that matter to you? Note that R1 is only specified to be within +/- 1/3rd its nominal value and the ratio of the two resistors varies from 8 to 12. If just one-off, test it in the circumstances you will be using it. But this sounds like you want to test several. In that case, it is worth setting up a test jig. A simple 9 V battery would suffice for the power supply. So pretty simple to do. And thanks for adding info.

(I've added the transistor's details into the question where they should be, and removed earlier comments which asked for those details as they are now obsolete.)

I have in display board with this transistor that is suspected as defective - its emitter is connected to 13v power - display board doesn't work- I think that dvm diode mode test is sufficent to conclude its functionality - just to know if I should get some voltage between B&E

I don't think you can conclude that the transistor is faulty from that. If it was shorted E-C (a more likely failure mode than just open) you could conclude it was faulty, other than that it's hard to say without knowing a lot more about how the DMM works.
I suggest testing it functionally in a switching circuit.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
LED is off with SW1 open (not pressed), LED is on with SW1 closed (pressed)
